# How can I use an already-loaded Visual Studio 2010 instance as my git commit editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, git

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010, but using Git from the command line (for now, at least).  When I do a `git commit`, it opens some editor I don't know.

I've been able to set Notepad as the commit message editor like this:

- `git config --global core.editor notepad.exe`

I was able to get it to use Visual Studio 2010 like this:

- `git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe'"`

But what I want to do is set git to use an already-running instance of Visual Studio 2010, if possible.

The [/Edit command line switch for devenv.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991989.aspx) is supposed to be able to do this, but what syntax should I use in the `git config` line?

**EDIT**:  It appears that this works...but not entirely:

`git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe' -edit"`

I say "not entirely" because, while it does indeed open the commit message file in the running instance of VS 2010, git also immediately gives me the "There was a problem with the editor" message.  And saving the file doesn't do anything.  It seems as if git expects the commit message editor to open (rather than already be open), and to close when the message is complete.

Comment: Does adding `/Edit` to right after the single quote after `devenv.exe` work?

Comment: The editor git is opening by default, especially if you are using msys-git, is most likely vim.

Comment: I think this fundamentally wouldn't work, because Git will open the editor, then wait for that spawned process to exit.  In the case of using the already-open VS instance, Git won't know when you are done editing the file, because you wont be closing VS after the edit.

Comment: @rally25rs, is there a way to reconfigure Git to just watch for the file to get saved, instead of waiting for the editor to exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Notepad2 or Notepad++. They are developer oriented editors but still quite simple and easy to use. They will handle the line endings just fine (which is the problem with mixing notepad.exe with git). Notepad2 is a better choice than Notepad++ in this case IMO.

Comment: While technically this isn't what I was looking for, it's a decent solution, given the apparent limitation of git that requires the editor to open and close in conjunction with the commit message file.  Notepad2 seems pretty fast and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want VS for commit edits because you are doing your source code editing in there too, right?

If you are starting down the road to integration like this, you probably just want to install [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) and be done with it. That will integrate Git into your VisualStudio environemnt nicely for you.

This will make it much easier for you. The command line is really best used by folks familiar with unix commands. If you are intimidated by things like the `vi` editor, you probably should avoid it.

If you really want to stick with the command line, I'd suggest using something lighter than VisualStudio for simple commit edits. Notepad will probably work fine. Commit edits are just simple text. You don't need VisualStudio for that.

Comment: I prefer to use git on the command line for now.  But I don't want to use vi.  An editor that doesn't give any indication of how to save and exit doesn't strike me as terribly user-friendly.

Comment: @Kyralessa - Well, as an Emacs partisan, I can't fault you there. My suggestion in that case would be to bring up something else simple like Notepad then. VisualStudio would be swatting a gnat with a Sledgehammer.

Comment: I'd be content to use notepad, but the git status message that appears uses lf instead of crlf, so in notepad it all runs together on one line.  Is there a way to have it use crlf instead?  (I don't care if it checks in with lf, as long as it uses crlf in notepad.)

Comment: @Kyralessa - Got me on that one. I know there are different CRLF settings you can use for your project, but the docs just talk about them affecting how files themselves are checked in, not their comments. You could try playing with them to see. (Warning: Switching settings on an existing project will make every line in every file appear to have changed).

Comment: I suppose you **could** go download emacs and use it. It is (many would argue) much more user-friendly than vi, and can handle alternate line endings. That's a wee bit much just for check-in comments though.

Comment: I would recommend using Notepad++ or Notepad2. They are developer oriented editors but still quite simple and easy to use. They will handle the line endings just fine. Notepad2 is a better choice than Notepad++ in this case IMO.

Comment: @Matt Greer, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Notepad2 seems reasonably quick and lightweight for what I need.

Comment: @Kyralessa -- ok, made it into an answer.